# Bad performance of parallel subroutine

Tags: fortran, openmp

I was trying to parallelize the following code; however, when it was executed on the main program, there didn't seem to be significant speed-up. I tested the same subroutine on another program, and it took even longer time to run than the serial code.

```
      SUBROUTINE rotate(r,qt,n,np,i,a,b)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER n,np,i
      DOUBLE PRECISION a,b,r(np,np),qt(np,np)
      INTEGER j
      DOUBLE PRECISION c,fact,s,w,y
      if(a.eq.0.d0)then
        c=0.d0
        s=sign(1.d0,b)
      else if(abs(a).gt.abs(b))then
        fact=b/a
        c=sign(1.d0/sqrt(1.d0+fact**2),a)
        s=fact*c
      else
        fact=a/b
        s=sign(1.d0/sqrt(1.d0+fact**2),b)
        c=fact*s
      endif
!$omp parallel shared(i,n,c,s,r,qt) private(y,w,j)
!$omp do schedule(static,2)

      do 11 j=i,n
        y=r(i,j)
        w=r(i+1,j)
        r(i,j)=c*y-s*w
        r(i+1,j)=s*y+c*w
 11   continue

!$omp do schedule(static,2)  

      do 12 j=1,n
        y=qt(i,j)
        w=qt(i+1,j)
        qt(i,j)=c*y-s*w
        qt(i+1,j)=s*y+c*w
 12   continue
!$omp end parallel
      return
      END
C  (C) Copr. 1986-92 Numerical Recipes Software Vs94z&):9+X%1j49#:`*.
```

However when I used the built-in function in Linux to measure the time, i got:

```
real 0m12.160s

user 4m49.894s

sys 0m0.880s
```

which is ridiculous compared to the time of the serial code:

```
real 0m2.078s

user 0m2.068s

sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Welcome. How did you measure the time? Don't forget to take the [Tour].

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I measured time using the built-in function <time> in Linux. The first time I run this subroutine by plugging in random numbers, and I got 4 minutes and 44 minutes as my real time and user time. However, the serial code gave me something like 3 minutes so the result is not desirable. The second time I run this subroutine with a 20-page super duper long main code, I got around 13 minutes for both the real time and the user time. I guess in the second time the code wasn't actually parallelised since the user time is not significantly bigger than the real time. am i right?

Comment: I cant copy paste my codes here loool it goes messed up when i paste it :((((

Comment: program schmid
  integer size
  parameter(size=100)
  double precision::a(size,size),b(size,size),c(size,size),d(size,size)
  integer i,j,k
  external rotate

  
  do i=1,size
     do j=1,size
        a(i,j)=dble(abs(sqrt((real(i+j)/2+1)+400)-30)*12)
        b(i,j)=dble(i*j**3*abs(i-j)-22)
        c(i,j)=dble(a(j,i)*b(i,j)*(a(i,j)-b(i,j))/23)
        d(i,j)=dble((a(i,j)-a(j,i)+b(i,j)*b(j,i)-c(i,j)**2)**2-900)
        do k=1,size
           call rotate(a,b,size,size,k,a(i,k),-a(i,k+1))
           call rotate(c,d,size,size,k,c(i,k),-c(i,k+1))
        enddo
     enddo
  enddo

Comment: Vladimir, actually I wonder if the slow-down of the parallel code was due to the overloaded information in the "shared variable" part. cuz in order that the loop could assign new values to the elements of the matrix, the matrix needs to have the type of "shared". however when the matrix is too big will this slow down my program though?

Comment: (As I commented under your new question:) You can edit your question.

Comment: yahhh i copy pasted that question here i am gonna delete that one atm

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete program. It is not possible to read it from the comment. See [ask] and [mcve]. Add important stuff, stuff like "thanks in advance" is not necessary, it clutters the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have something like

```
do i=1,n
  do j=1,n
    do k=1,n
      call rotate()
    end do
  end do
end do
```

for `n = 100` and you are parallelizing two simple loops inside `rotate`.

That is hopeless. If you want decent performance, you must parallelize the outermost loop that is possible.

There is simply not enough work inside the loops inside `rotate` and it is called too many times. You call it 1000000 times so the threads must be synchronised or re-launched 2000000 times. That takes all of your run time. All the run time increase you see is this synchronization.

Comment: Oh this absolutely makes a lot of sense! Thank you Vladimir my best regards from Quebec Canada hahahaha :)